# How do I mock Func<T> factory dependency to return different objects using AutoMock?

Tags: testing, moq, autofac

I'm trying to write a test for a class that has a constructor dependency on `Func<T>`. In order to complete successfully the function under test needs to create a number of separate objects of type `T`.

When running in production, AutoFac generates a new `T` every time `factory()` is called, however when writing a test using AutoMock it returns the same object when it is called again.

Test case below showing the difference in behaviour when using AutoFac and AutoMock. I'd expect both of these to pass, but the AutoMock one fails.

```
public class TestClass
{
    private readonly Func<TestDep> factory;

    public TestClass(Func<TestDep> factory)
    {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    public TestDep Get()
    {
        return factory();
    }
}

public class TestDep
{}

[TestMethod()]
public void TestIt()
{
    using var autoMock = AutoMock.GetStrict();

    var testClass = autoMock.Create<TestClass>();

    var obj1 = testClass.Get();
    var obj2 = testClass.Get();

    Assert.AreNotEqual(obj1, obj2);
}

[TestMethod()]
public void TestIt2()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    builder.RegisterSource(new AnyConcreteTypeNotAlreadyRegisteredSource());
            
    var container = builder.Build();

    var testClass = container.Resolve<TestClass>();
            
    var obj1 = testClass.Get();
    var obj2 = testClass.Get();

    Assert.AreNotEqual(obj1, obj2);
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us more about why you're doing it this way? For example, usually Autofac fills in `Func<T>` from the container and you just register `T`. Have you tried creating a real container but with mock objects inside it? It may be you can solve the problem by doing mocking in a different way, so knowing why can help folks better answer you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've updated my code example to hopefully be a little clearer, so we've got `TestIt` where we're using AutoMock and `TestIt2` where we just use Autofac directly.

Comment: In this case, I don't think mock objects are particularly relevant (although our real test case does include them). I guess we could look to just use Autofac directly here - although it would be nice to understand why this is happening so we can correctly decide when to use AutoMock/Autofac in the future.

Comment: Stepping through my tests with the source code for AutoMock - it looks like the default registration is InstancePerLifetimeScope, rather than the AutoFac default of InstancePerDependency. This would certainly cause what i'm seeing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AutoMock (from the [Autofac.Extras.Moq package](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.Extras.Moq)) is primarily useful for setting up complex mocks. Which is to say, you have a single object with a lot of dependencies and it's really hard to set that object up because it doesn't have a parameterless constructor. Moq doesn't let you set up objects with constructor parameters by default, so having something that fills the gap is useful.

However, the mocks you get from it are treated like any other mock you might get from Moq. When you set up a mock instance with Moq, you're not getting a new one every time unless you also implement the factory logic yourself.

**AutoMock is not for mocking Autofac behavior.** The `Func<T>` support where Autofac calls a resolve operation on every call to the `Func<T>` - that's Autofac, not Moq.

It makes sense for AutoMock to use `InstancePerLifetimeScope` because, just like setting up mocks with plain Moq, you need to be able to get the mock instance back to configure it and validate against it. It would be much harder if it was new every time.

Obviously there are ways to work around that, and with a non-trivial amount of breaking changes you could probably implement `InstancePerDependency` semantics in there, but there's really not much value in doing that at this point since that's not really what this is for... and you could always create two different `AutoMock` instances to get two different mocks.

A much better way to go, in general, is to provide useful abstractions and use Autofac with mocks in the container.

For example, say you have something like...

```cs
public class ThingToTest
{
  public ThingToTest(PackageSender sender) { /* ... */ }
}

public class PackageSender
{
  public PackageSender(AddressChecker checker, DataContext context) { /* ... */ }
}

public class AddressChecker { }

public class DataContext { }
```

If you're trying to set up `ThingToTest`, you can see how also setting up a `PackageSender` is going to be complex, and you'd likely want something like AutoMock to handle that.

However, you can make your life easier by introducing an interface there.

```cs
public class ThingToTest
{
  public ThingToTest(IPackageSender sender) { /* ... */ }
}

public interface IPackageSender { }

public class PackageSender : IPackageSender { }
```

By hiding all the complexity behind the interface, you now can mock just `IPackageSender` using plain Moq (or whatever other mocking framework you like, or even creating a manual stub implementation). You wouldn't even need to include Autofac in the mix because you could mock the dependency directly and pass it in.

Point being, you can design your way into making testing and setup easier, which is why, in the comments on your question, I asked *why* you were doing things that way (which, at the time of this writing, never did get answered). I would strongly recommend designing things to be easier to test if possible.

Comment: Thanks for the very comprehensive answer! Yes, I think I understand what's occurring now.

Comment: I definitely had a misconception about where Func was being dealt with, so that's really useful.

And, yes, I did miss the *why*. The short answer - i don't really know why it is the way it is! The longer answer, it's for a product that's been in development for 10 years, autofac was introduced several years into development. This area doesn't have good test coverage, so we're trying to improve test coverage while keeping changes to a minimum before we look to refactor.